# Inkscape is breaking Pattern Object before distributing it Along Path

Tags: inkscape, patterns

Using the Extension [Pattern Along Path](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Extensions-GenerateFromPath.html#Extensions-Scatter) from Inkscape, I am trying to have a scatter plot effect by distributing small rectangles along a path. Inkscape is achieving this except that the rectangle is broken at the upper left corner as shown in the attached figure:

[image]

Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: I just tried this using as pattern a rectangle (created with the rectangle tool) that I transformed into a path with Path > Object to Path. I did not have the same problem. Same with creating the rectangle using the bézier tool (but I did pay attention to close it). How did you create the rectangle?

Comment: My bad. I didn't convert first to a path ! I first thought that one of the elements has to be a path, but actually, even rectangles, circles ...have to be converted to a path

Answer (score 2):

If the rectangle you use as pattern is a path, this problem does not occur. You can draw a rectangle (with the rectangle tool) and then convert it to path (Path > Object to Path) or you can draw the rectangle with the bézier tool (making sure it is properly closed).